# SOTI Encryption on Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, soti

A possible candidate for the tumbleweed badge...

We're using SOTI to control our Windows Mobile devices and are encrypting certain files and directories on the device.

SOTI encryption runs, effectively, in the background and we need a way of knowing when it's finished (so we can restore access to the imapcted applications).

Does anyone know of a way of identifying whether SOTI has finished encryption a file or directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While SOTI is encrypting a particular file, it creates a temp file with the same name and some extension (sorry, I don't remember the extension).  You could conceivably poll for the existence of this temp file, and assume the file is finished encrypting when it goes away.

A similar method might work for a whole directory - keep checking the directory until you don't see any file with the temporary extension.  You'd want to make sure you don't find a temp file for a couple of seconds, to make sure you don't accidentally catch SOTI between files.

If I recall correctly, SOTI also displays a message box (on the Windows side) when encryption is complete.  You could poll for this box popping up in a variety of ways.

Comment: Sorry to kill your shot at the tumbleweed badge.

Comment: If you solve the problem I won't care...  I'll give this a go.